# Access SQL syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

My problem is that I have a code in MS Access 2010 that throws syntax error. This is a code of a query.

```
select distinct Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No], atabla.[Outgoing date] as ext1date, btabla.[outgoing date] as plg1date, ctabla.[outgoing date] as str1date
from (((Daily_Output20151013
inner join (select Daily_Output20151013.[lot no] 
from (Daily_Output20151013.[outgoing date] 
where Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern] = 'a') as atabla on Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No] = atabla.[Lot No])
inner join (select [lot no], [outgoing date] from Daily_Output20151013     
where Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern] = 'b') as btabla on Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No] = btabla.[Lot No])
inner join (select [lot no], [outgoing date] from Daily_Output20151013
where Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern] = 'c') as ctabla on 
Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No] = ctabla.[Lot No])
```

Daily_Output20151013 is an existing table, atabla, btabla and ctabla are tables that are not existing yet, and I need them for the query.
Outgoing date and Lot No also exist.

- I've done what @GorezTrol offered to me, but it still throws syntax error: ''Syntax error in FROM''

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: You are missing the `from` clauses in your inner selects. And you need more parentheses in Access when joining more than 1 table

Comment: There are a couple of ossies here. The main one is the selects after the inner joins. They don't contain a `from` clause with table at all. Apart from that, you also need to group multiple joins with parentheses, so you get `from (((Daily_Output inner join Something) inner join Something) inner join.... )`.

Comment: It is nearly always best to use the query design window in MS Access.

Comment: @Fionnuala: yes, I agree with you for the most cases, but I do not really know how to solve this problem in query designer.

Comment: @GolezTrol The from clauses are missing, because the name of the tables are not written in one word (for example: Lot No, not LotNo) and I thought that this was the cause why access threw syntax error. However I'm not allowed to modify the table names. I'm sure there are much more problems, because at first I wrote it with from, and it didn't work. Thanks for the parentheses advice, I will try it in a little time.

Comment: Just like the field names, you can (and must) write the table names within square brackets too. You cannot just omit the from clause.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thank you, I've made your suggestions, but it still throws syntax error (see up).